# convert image to gray scale and save by custom class BitmapSaver

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I want to save an image after converting it to Gray Scale Image. But I have a problem with saving image after converting it. I successfully covert the image to gray scale by as3, but when I save this color modified image by a Custom class BitmapSaver, the saved image is again of original colors not gray scale. I'm not understanding why this so?
If any one knows about this issue, so please help me....!!!
Thanks In Advance...!!!

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Loader;
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
import com.flashandmath.dg.bitmapUtilities.BitmapSaver;

var imageFilter=new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png");
var fileR:FileReference=new FileReference();
fileR.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
fileR.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

pickbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,selectImage);

function selectImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
   fileR.browse([imageFilter]);
}
function selectHandler(e:Event):void{
   trace("selectHandler: "+fileR.name);
   fileR.load(); 
}
function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
   trace("completeHandler: " + fileR.name);
   var ba:ByteArray=fileR.data;
   var loader:Loader=new Loader();
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
   loader.loadBytes(ba);
}
var bm:Bitmap;

function loaded(e:Event):void{

   bm = e.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap;

   addChild(bm);
   adjustColor();
}

function adjustColor():void
{
    var ac:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();

    ac.brightness = 20;
    ac.hue = 0;
    ac.saturation = -100;
    ac.contrast = 40;

    var ar:Array = ac.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
    var cl:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(ar);

    var filter:Array = new Array(cl);
    bm.filters = filter;

    var saver:BitmapSaver = new BitmapSaver(bm.bitmapData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you apply a custom filter to the image, and then you save the `bitmapData`. Filter do not modify the `bitmapData` by themselves, which means that Flash takes care to manipulate the image when drawing it. Think of this like a Blur filter applied into Flash IDE - it will make the image blurred, but it won't modify the original image, right?

So you just need to use a simple `draw` to take the modified BitmapData and use it, similar to this:

```
var modified:BitmapData = new BitmapData(original.width, original.heigth);
modified.draw(original);

var saver:BitmapSaver = new BitmapSaver(modified);
```

This should do the trick, maybe with little tweaking.

**EDIT**:
As @George Profenza provided in comments, there is another good option. If you don't need the original BitmapData, you can directly set a filter into it, and not the display object. This way the original source will be changed and using any kind of saver will do the trick directly. Keep in mind that you won't be able to reverse it.

Anyways this is a good approach having in mind that you won't need to create a second BitmapData object, which means that you won't have memory increased.

So depending on the need of having the original BitmapData, either copy/clone it, or use filter directly on it.

Cheers!

Comment: Another option is to [apply the filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#applyFilter()) to the BitmapData directly (e.g. `bm.bitmapDataa.applyFilter(bm.bitmapData,new Rectangle(0,0,bm.bitmapData.width,bm.bitmapData.height),new Point(),cl);`

Comment: Very true! Didn't think of this, and it's even a better approach (if you don't need the original bitmap), as it won't create more objects, thus less memory (at about half the size :))

Comment: Well! This technique is very use full... I'm sharing the BitmapSaver Class with how it works also. (Link Removed)

Comment: The technique of @George Profenza is also very usefull, having little use of memory...